# Call to undefined function enchant_broker_init()

Tags: php, macos, enchant

I am trying to implement the tinyMCE spellchecker plugin and I have encountered a problem with enabling PHPs enchant module.

The following code

```
$enchant = enchant_broker_init();
print_r($enchant);
```

Returns the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function enchant_broker_init()
```

I am running PHP v5.4.30 on Mac OSX 10.9.5 if that helps at all.

Do I need to do anything in Terminal to enable it or should it already be enabled?

Comment: Enchant should be bundled with PHP from v5.3 on, but needs to be compiled into PHP according to http://php.net/manual/en/enchant.installation.php

Comment: @CBroe That's what I'm having a problem with. Any idea how I go about doing that?